# Is $ (A∪B)×(C∩D)=(A×C)∪(B×D)$ true for all sets A,B,C and D?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is  $(A\cup B)\times(C\cap D)=(A\times C)\cup (B \times D)$ true for all sets $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$?

I have no idea what to do here. How could I possibly go about trying to prove this? 
Or disprove it?
It's not exactly the same question with the previous one
First I tried to prove that both sides are equal if $(A\cup B)\times(C\cap D)\subseteq(A×C)∪(B×D)$ and $(A×C)∪(B×D)\subseteq(A\cup B)\times(C\cap D)$ .

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this equality is correct, the best way to guess whether it is true is where did the $\cap$ go? Then we can start generating counter examples

Comment: Please show us some of your thought/work. [Your last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424142/is-a∪b×c∩d-a∪c×b∪d-true-for-all-sets-a-b-c-and-d) should have given you enough hints to start, specifically John Griffin's answer.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this was an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Math_QED No. It was not exact duplicate. But along the same line.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a **counterexample**, which proves that **set equality does not hold**.

Let $A = \{1\}, B = \{1\}, C =\{1\}, D= \{1,2\}$

Then, $(A\cup B) \times (C \cap D) = \{1\} \times \{1\} = \{(1,1)\}$

$(A\times C) \cup (B \times D) = \{(1,1)\} \cup \{(1,1),(1,2)\} = \{(1,1),(1,2)\}$

so there is no set equality.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(x,y)$ is in the set on the left. Then $x\in A\cup B$ and $y\in C\cap D$. In the case $x\in A$, then $(x,y)\in A\times C$, and in the case $x\in B$, then $(x,y)\in B\times D$. In either case, we have inclusion in that direction.

On the other hand, suppose $(z,w)$ is in the set on the right. Then we have two cases: either $z\in A$ and $w\in C$, or else $z\in B$ and $w\in D$. This does establish that $z\in A\cup B$, but it does not show that $w$ has to be in $C\cap D$. In order to find a counterexample, look at sets $C$ and $D$ that have a non-empty symmetric difference.

Comment: *For OP:* This answer, along with John Griffin's answer in your previous question, will give you the general philosophy about how to construct counter examples for this type of problems. Try to understand this philosophy, instead of focusing too much on a particular counter example. Hopefully you will come up with more more counter examples. :) @Tony: (+1) of course for such a nice explanation.